Join tables on secondary condition if primary condition doesn't exist
We are trying to conditionally join two tables, and if the first join condition isn't available, we would like to join on a second condition. In the example below, we want to find the price for each fruit and colour combination from the table below by looking up the dummy_pricing table.
If a price for the fruit and colour combination does not exist in the dummy_pricing table, we want it to use the fruit price with a null colour instead.
Sample tables query and output below. Would appreciate anyone's help in understanding where I am going wrong here.
Table Structure
dummy_prods table



style
colour
size




apple
red
S


apple
red
M


apple
red
L


apple
green
L


apple
green
M


apple
green
S


orange
green
S


apple
purple
S



dummy_pricing table



style
colour
price




apple
red
10


apple
green
15


apple

17



Example Query:
SELECT *
FROM dummy_prods PRODUCTS         
LEFT JOIN dummy_prices PRICING on PRODUCTS.style = PRICING.style    
AND PRICING.colour = (CASE                              
WHEN PRODUCTS.colour = PRICING.colour THEN PRODUCTS.colour END)

This is the result from that query



PRODUCTS.style
PRODUCTS.colour
PRODUCTS.size
PRICING.style
PRICING.colour
PRICING.price




apple
red
S
apple
red
10


apple
red
M
apple
red
10


apple
red
L
apple
red
10


apple
green
L
apple
green
15


apple
green
M
apple
green
15


apple
green
S
apple
green
15


orange
green
S





apple
purple
S






The example of a desired result



PRODUCTS.style
PRODUCTS.colour
PRODUCTS.size
PRICING.style
PRICING.colour
PRICING.price




apple
red
S
apple
red
10


apple
red
M
apple
red
10


apple
red
L
apple
red
10


apple
green
L
apple
green
15


apple
green
M
apple
green
15


apple
green
S
apple
green
15


apple
purple
S
apple

17




you could use an outer apply in stead of a join
select prod.style as [PRODUCTS.style], 
       prod.colour as [PRODUCTS.colour], 
       prod.size as [PRODUCTS.size],
       price.style as [PRICING.style],
       price.colour as [PRICING.colour],
       price.price as [PRICING.prize]
from   dummy_prods prod
  outer apply ( select top 1
                       p.style,
                       p.colour,
                       p.price
                from   dummy_pricing p
                where  p.style = prod.style
                and    (p.colour = prod.colour or p.colour is null)
                order by case when p.colour is not null then 1 else 2 end
              ) price

see dbfiddle here



PRODUCTS.style
PRODUCTS.colour
PRODUCTS.size
PRICING.style
PRICING.colour
PRICING.prize




apple
red
S
apple
red
10


apple
red
M
apple
red
10


apple
red
L
apple
red
10


apple
green
L
apple
green
15


apple
green
M
apple
green
15


apple
green
S
apple
green
15


orange
green
S
null
null
null


apple
purple
S
apple
null
17



If you want orange not included, like if you used an inner join, than just change outer apply to cross apply
See this dbfiddle



PRODUCTS.style
PRODUCTS.colour
PRODUCTS.size
PRICING.style
PRICING.colour
PRICING.prize




apple
red
S
apple
red
10


apple
red
M
apple
red
10


apple
red
L
apple
red
10


apple
green
L
apple
green
15


apple
green
M
apple
green
15


apple
green
S
apple
green
15


apple
purple
S
apple
null
17




If the price for a null colour is lower than a specified colour, this will select the null price over a specific match. Better to order by the null-or-not condition.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever What do you mean with the null-or-not condition order by. I already added an order by, by the way

Imagine the price for the apple, null row has a price of 8. Your query is going to select that price for all apples, regardless of the colour matches. Per the question, you should only be selecting the null match if the colour match fails, so your order by logic should be based on that, not the price.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever Ah yes, I see, I updated the answer

I think order by case when p.colour is null then 0 else 1 end desc is what you need, or perhaps order by case when p.colour is not null then 1 else 2 end, which might be more intuitive to read.

@TN OK I updated the answer with the second alternative
